# IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'True'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null

Tags: cookies, okta

I am implementing OKTA authentication in one of my asp.net c# application where I am facing below issue since long time.

**IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'True'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.**

This issue is with all browsers other then IE, it works smooth in IE
I have tried setting cookie same site mode = Lax, but still there is no luck.
Any help with this is highly appreciated.

I have tried setting cookie same site mode = Lax, but still there is no luck.