# Error: IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am following instructions from here [Validate Azure AD token in a .NET 4.7 API without messing actual validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683653/validate-azure-ad-token-in-a-net-4-7-api-without-messing-actual-validation/74703197#74703197)

In the sample code, I have not made any change, except, I am using HTTP instead of HTTPS

I am getting this error after sign-in

[image]

> "Error: IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'.
> OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null,
> OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The
> nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set
> OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a
> 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated."

Here is my startup.cs file look like

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AppModelv2_WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Startup))]

namespace AppModelv2_WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

        // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
        string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

        // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
        static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

        // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Microsoft identity platform endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
        string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,                
                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

After taking AD credentials on MS login page, it is called OnAuthenticationFailed method in startup.cs file. What am I missing here? Is SSL HTTPS compulsory on local hosts? If Yes, Can I make it work with HTTP on local? I am using Visual Studio 2015.

REF: [IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'True'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77360644/idx21323-requirenonce-is-true-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-w)

Comment: It seems SSL is compulsory, I have enable https by following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048613/376702

Comment: Where you have changed to `http` in `RedirectURI` AD ?

Comment: In Project Properties, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420879/how-to-integrate-azure-ad-authentication-in-asp-net-on-net-4-7-web-applicatio